# ESLint crawl ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, eslint, es6-modules

I have a project using [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) that I would like to add linting for.

Here is what I have in my `.eslintrc` file:

```
env:
  browser: true
  es6: true
extends: 'eslint:recommended'
parserOptions:
  sourceType: module
```

My ESLint invocation looks like this: `eslint script.js` where `script.js` has `import` statements to other modules in my project.

`script.js` is being linted just fine, **but ESLint is not continuing on to it's specified `import`s**.

Is there a way to make ESLint crawl my source for me? Perhaps this isn't the default behavior...if not, is there a best practice to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by invoking eslint for each separate file like this:

```
find web -name "*.js" | xargs eslint
```

Certain directories (like `web/build`) are excluded with:

```
find web -name "*.js" ! -path "web/build/*" | xargs eslint
```